# What is the return of Task?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task

For the past few weeks, I have been looking at Tasks and I really struggled with them. One of the things that I have struggled was creating an awaitable method that has no return type.

Now we now that the non awaitable methods work like this:

```
//This is a method with a return type:
private string methodWithReturn()
{
     return "This is a string return type";
}
//This is a method without a return type
private void methodWithoutReturn()
{
    //Some random code that has no return
}
```

Now when it comes to Tasks, it's really complicated. There are three types: `void`, `Task` and `Task<T>`
`void` is not recommended at all, so I am left with the two Tasks. Here is the problem. I want to have a Task without a return type and this is a code:

```
private Task taskTypeMethod()
{
    //some random code
}
```

The issue here is that it still issues a warning that "not all code paths return a value". Am I understanding Tasks incorrectly or what am I doing wrong here?

I was told to Add `async` before it, but that requires me to use the `await` keyword inside the code block, which I won't be using.

Comment: If you're not using `async` *and* you're not going to return a live `Task`, why have a `Task` as a return type at all?

Comment: Can you show what do you have inside `taskTypeMethod` ?  It sounds like you're doing something synchronous inside. Then why bother returning `Task` ?

Comment: You are indeed understanding Tasks incorrectly. Reading a little more about them and following some tutorials would probably help a ton.

Comment: So what are you actually doing that's asynchronous.  If you have nothing to `await` that implies that you have no asynchronous operation to perform, so you shouldn't be using tasks at all.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel No, I mean asynchronous.  Clearly this method is designed to represent performing some asynchronous operation(s), if it needs to return a task.

Comment: @Servy reading your comment again, I understood that. But I believe OP is doing completely synchronous operation we can't say without the code.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Yes, which is why I asked what asynchronous operations he is performing.  If the answer is none, then we know the method shouldn't return a `Task`.

Answer (score 2):

Without returning a `Task`, how could a caller find out when the async computation you presumably are running is completed? If nobody needs to know, make the method return `Task` and have the return value ignored. If that is not possible for some reason you can use `async void`.

How you generate the `Task` to return is not important to know for callers. An easy way is to make the method `async Task`.

> The issue here is that it still issues a warning that "not all code paths return a value".

Well, that error makes sense. You promise to return something but you don't. That can't work. Either get hold of some `Task` and return it or use `async Task`. Maybe you need to find out what `async` even means.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be understanding `Task` incorrectly.

If you set up a method like this:

```
private Task taskTypeMethod()
{
  //some random code
}
```

... then you have to return a `Task` object.  That's a basic requirement of methods:  those that have return types need to return a value of that type.

But that doesn't mean the `Task` itself has to return a value when it finishes.  You could do something like this:

```
Task t = Task.Run( () => // some random code );
```

That would give you a `Task` that would execute your "random code".  But the "random code" wouldn't need to return a value.